# References for a representation theorem proof

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Could someone recommend a reference for a proof of this Representation Theorem that Wikipedia attributes to Riesz?

Theorem: Every continuous linear functional $A[f]$ over the space $C([0, 1])$ of continuous functions in the interval $[0,1]$ can be represented in the form $$A[f]=\int_0^1 f(x)d\alpha(x)$$ where $\alpha(x)$ is of bounded variation on $[0,1]$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harro Heuser: Functional Analysis (Wiley & Sons),

Example $35.3$

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it :)